# SytanxError: Invalid Sytax

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I have been working on my homework that gives step by step instructions on how to Execute a code using the another code file as input.

I'm not as familiar with python, and I've been searching everywhere to see what easy mistake I am probably making but I just can't find out what it could be just by getting the same syntax error

animals.csv is an excel file that I want to be read by kingdom.py which maps certain elements in the animals.csv

- I've made sure I'm spelling the file names of my code correctly
- I've placed all documents in my root directory of my mac and other directories as well
- I've tried using IDLE and mac built in python program but keep getting the same error.

```
>>> cat animals.csv | python3 kingdom.py
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

The output should be a long list in the end, but this is just step one out of 3 that I can't get passed

Comment: Python can't run bash/ms-dos commands, you can try that with `os.system(cmd)`.

Answer (score 4):

You are in [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html), which is Python's IDE.  The commands/binaries that you're executing, `cat` and `python3`, are known to your shell (such as [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))), not to Python itself.

In IDLE, type `exit()` or `quit()`.  Then, open a [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) emulator, such as `Terminal.app` on Mac OS X, in your Applications folder.   This gives you access to a shell (Bash) where you can enter `cat animals.csv | python3 kingdom.py`.

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is a Linux command for you bash, but Python doesn't recognize bash commands (IPython recognizes, but "pure" Python don't do this).

You can use Linux commands on a Jupyter Notebook, for example with the "!" before your command. For example:

```py
!ls
```

This will listen the files on your actual folder.

Comment: Irrelevant if you are trying to pipe a stream to a Python file, which she is trying to do

Comment: Yes. It is only a example of how using bash commands on Python. But, at all, Python doesn't recognize bash commands.